# General matrix element in weak interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, weak-interaction

During my studies on weak interactions and $\beta$-decay, I've to study how theory and experimental results bring us to achieve the V-A structure of weak vertices. My doubts regard the theory.

Suppose the following lagrangian for the $\beta$-deacy:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{G_F}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_a (\overline\psi_D\Gamma^a\psi_B)(\overline\psi_C\Gamma_a(c_a+c'_a\gamma_5)\psi_A) 
$$

Where $\Gamma_a = \{1, \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\mu\gamma_5, \sigma^{\mu\nu}, \gamma_5\}$ (PVATS) is a linear combination of bilinear covariants. From my understand $c'_a$ is requested to include parity violation (which is observed in experiments), no problems with that.

*First question*. It is said on my teacher's notes that in the non-relativistic limit the bilinear covariants transform with these couplings: S and V transform with the identity, A and T transform with the $\vec{\sigma}$ matrices (it is not clear to me in which sense he says "they transform with..."). This is not clear to me why, I think it has to do with two concepts: the large and small components of Dirac equation, and the differences in $\Delta J$ in Fermi transition and Gamow-Teller transition. But this is not yet so clear in my mind why. Also this: is the ordering of the bilinear covariants that I listed before relevant? Why the pseudoscalar term is at the end?

*Second question*. His notes skip the calculus of $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ but at the end for a general transition it comes out that

$$
|\mathcal{M}|^2 \propto [c_s^2(1-\vec\beta_e\cdot\vec\beta_\nu) + \frac{2}{\gamma_e}c_sc_v + c_v^2(1+\vec\beta_e\cdot\vec\beta_nu)]\bigl|\langle N'|I_+|N\rangle\bigr|^2 + 
[c_t^2(1+\frac{1}{3}\vec\beta_e\cdot\vec\beta_\nu) - \frac{2}{\gamma_e}c_tc_a + c_a^2(1-\frac{1}{3}\vec\beta_e\cdot\vec\beta_nu)]\bigl|\langle N'|\sum_iI_+^{(i)}\sigma^{(i)}|N\rangle\bigr|^2
$$

And I can't figure out how to start and then to obtain such a result.

*Third question*. Where is the pseudoscalar term?

Any help or clarification will be grateful.

Comment: Link to your teacher's notes?

Comment: Strong advice. Go to a reputable text instead of trying to parse out notes you are puzzled by and the reader cannot access...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm unable to find a reputable text, I tried Halzen-Martin and Thomson but they did the same thing: they skip the calculus part.

Comment: Weak Interactions of Leptons and Quarks, 
by Eugene D. Commins &  Philip H. Bucksbaum